# How to scrape Facebook advertising data?

Tags: facebook, scrape

Facebook provides data about demographics via their advertising platform. How to scrape it (using Python)?

1.) go to http://www.facebook.com/ads/create/

2.) fill in the forms

3.) now, there is data

See sample image: http:// www.webdistortion.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/fb4.jpg
(i am a new user, so I can't post a image)

Problem: how to scrape it?

My ideas:

1.) use mechanize - maybe it is possible to fill in the forms, but the estimated number (112,960 in the example) is not visible in the source code and therefore you cannot parse it => we should  do some other tricks, but what?

2.) use selenium (or windmill) - my recording was: open facebook.com --> click advertising --> click create ad --> ...

Unfortunately, this already failed. Log:

> ```
> [info] Executing: |open | / | |
> ```
>
> [info] Executing: |clickAndWait | link=Advertising | |
>      [error] isNewPageLoaded found an old pageLoadError: Error: Permission denied for >> to get property Location.href
>      [error] Permission denied for  to get property Location.href
>      [info] Executing: |clickAndWait | css=span.uiButtonText | |
>      [error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-browserbot.js, lineNumber -> 840

There is evidence that it is possible to scrape this data: http://www.checkfacebook.com/

Solving the problem is more interesting than the data itself (ofc, this data is certainly interesting). I know that there are solutions, but I cannot come up with any. It is killing me, please help.

Comment: Just a quick remark. When you say "not visible in the source code", you mean not visible in the original source code. If it shows on your screen, it's HTML, and hence present in the document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by scrape data. Do you mean using the public Ads API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/) and calling the reach estimate function (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate/)?

Comment: My goal is to get the data - maybe I can achieve it through Ads Api or using mechanize to fill in the "create ads" forms etc. I do not know. I did not know about Ads API before posting, but using Ads API needs registration.

Comment: Correct.  You should register your app with facebook before attempting to use any of their APIs.  Did the reachestimate call work for you?

Comment: You have to apply for the access to the Ads API. An app can access the Ads API only if the app is on the Ads API white-list. One of the  requirements is: run more than 10 million ad impressions via Facebook Ads (https://developers.facebook.com/marketingapis/apply/) This means that I cannot use reachestimate call.

Comment: Ok, so there's your answer, direct from Facebook.   :)  I hope I got you pointed in the right direction.